# How to make overlapping shadow effect on 4 shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shadows

I'm trying to replicate a chain link effect on these 4 rackets and I wanted to add some depth by adding shadows on the intersection.

[image]

This is a rough idea of what I wanted to create. I did this using a shape that I applied a gradient from black to white and set the transparency to multiply.
The issue is that all these paths make a mess using the shape builder tool to cut out the shapes that will form the shadow.

Any ideas how can I go about this one?

Comment: Split it into pieces.

Comment: But the idea is advanced. Kill four flies (not only two) with one hit.